# Scala shortcut first solution in a for-comprehension list

Tags: scala, monads

I've got a coding draft which works so far as it delivers the correct answer. But from the esthetics side, it could be improved, my guess!
Aim: Find first solution in a list of many possible solutions. When found first solution, don't calculate further. In real-world application, the calculation of each solution/non-solution might be more complex for sure.
Don't like: The `Solution`=`Left` and `NoSolution`=`Right` aliasing is contra-intuitive, since `Right` normally stands for success and here Left and `Right` are swapped (since technically when using `Either` only `Left` shortcuts the for-comprehension list)
Is there a nice way to improve this implementation? or another solution?

```
package playground

object Test {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    test
  }

  val Solution = Left
  val NoSolution = Right

  def test: Unit = {
    {

      // Find the first solution in a list of computations and print it out

      val result = for {
        _ <- if (1 == 2) Solution("impossible") else NoSolution()
        _ <- NoSolution()
        _ <- NoSolution(3)
        _ <- Solution("*** Solution 1 ***")
        _ <- NoSolution("oh no")
        _ <- Solution("*** Solution 2 ***")
        x <- NoSolution("no, no")
      } yield x
      if (result.isLeft)
        println(result.merge)      // Prints:  *** Solution 1 ***
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What about something like this: `data.iterator.map(computeSolution).collecFirst { case Right(solution) => solution }` where `data` is a **List** of inputs to pass to `computeSolution` wich will return an `Either`. The bad thing about this is that if all fail, we lose the error messages.

Comment: Your question, and code, is a bit confusing. You say the aim is _"Find first solution in a list of many possible..."_ but there is no `List` in your code. Do the real-world solutions come already wrapped in the reverse-`Either` format or is that added just for the purposes of the `for` comprehension? If the latter, how is each "solution" tested for `Left`/`Right` assignment? The posted code does nothing if no correct solution is found. Is that the desired behavior? Is there nothing worth keeping/reporting in the `NoSolution` side of the `Either` results?

Comment: @jwvh: "a list in the code" refers to the items in `for { ... }`; real-world problems don't come wrapped in a reverse-`Either`, that is the proposal only as long as I cannot find a better one; the solution tests are e.g. the trivial "1==2" for demonstration (in test #1), but can get big; the code does nothing if no correct solution is found as this was the purpose; NoSolution details are not required, so they could even omitted entirely. Compared to exceptions handlers, where the first exception short cuts, here the first positive/solution should shortcut; no need to dig into the non-solutions

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking for something that's "monaduck": i.e. has `flatMap`/`map` but doesn't necessarily obey any monadic laws (Scala doesn't even require that `flatMap` have monadic shape: the chain after desugaring just has to typecheck); cf. duck-typing.

```
trait Trial[+Result] {
  def result: Option[Result]

  def flatMap[R >: Result](f: Unit => Trial[R]): Trial[R]
  def map[R](f: Result => R): Trial[R]
}

case object NoSolution extends Trial[Nothing] {
  def result = None
  def flatMap[R](f: Unit => Trial[R]): Trial[R] = f(())
  def map[R](f: Result => R): Trial[R] = this
}

case class Solution[Result](value: Result) extends Trial[Result] {
  def result = Some(value)
  def flatMap[R >: Result](f: Unit => Trial[R]): Trial[R] = this
  def map[R](f: Result => R): Trial[R] = Solution(f(value))
}
```

```
scala> for {
     |   _ <- if (1 == 2) Solution("nope") else NoSolution
     |   _ <- NoSolution
     |   _ <- Solution("yay!")
     |   _ <- NoSolution
     |   x <- Solution("nope")
     | } yield x
res0: Trial[String] = Solution(yay!)

scala> for {
     |   _ <- if (1 == 2) Solution("nope") else NoSolution
     |   _ <- NoSolution
     |   _ <- Solution("yay!")
     |   x <- NoSolution
     | } yield x
res1: Trial[String] = Solution(yay!)

scala> for {
     |   _ <- if (1 == 2) Solution("nope") else NoSolution
     |   x <- NoSolution
     | } yield x
res2: Trial[String] = NoSolution
```

Clearly, monadic laws are being violated: the only thing we could use for `pure` is `Solution`, but

```
scala> val f: Unit => Trial[Any] = { _ => NoSolution }
f: Unit => Trial[Any] = $Lambda$107382/0x00000008433be840@6c0e35d7

scala> Solution(5).flatMap(f)
res7: Trial[Any] = Solution(5)

scala> f(5)
<console>:13: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position
       f(5)
         ^
res8: Trial[Any] = NoSolution
```

Absent Scala's willingness to convert any pure value to `Unit`, that wouldn't even type check, but still, it breaks left identity.

Comment: Honestly should have made `f` in left identity a `Trial[Nothing]`...